# PHP get user input and keep new lines

Tags: php, lines

I have a string that needs to be interpreted by a program, which marks the beginning and the end of strings with a certain substring.

For example it understands

```
"Dog

The information I need

Cat"
```

But not

```
"DogTheinformationIneedCat" (or "Dog TheinformationIneed Cat")
```

Now the problem is I am retrieving the data from a user submitted textarea, but when this is taken it strips out all of the newlines and the data becomes useless.

How can I get input from the user and keep the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the lines are kept in the database in the form of `\n`

When taking text from the database, use the native php function `nl2br` which automatically converts the "newlines" into the html tag `<br`> there by preserving your new lines.

Just use it as `nl2br($your_string);`

for example:

```
function retrieve_data() {
    $data = get_data_from_db() // your get data function
    return nl2br($data); // this is where the magic happens *THIS IS NOT SAFE DON'T USE ON LIVE SERVER
}

save_data($data_from_text_area); // your save data function

echo retrieve_data() // will echo text with `<br`>
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Also, when outputting text from the database, always remember to **sanitize** the user input to avoid XSS attacks!

Example:

```
function sanitize_string($string) {
    return filter_var($string, FILTERS_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

echo nl2br(sanitize_string($string));
```

Comment: The data isn't coming from the DB, I'm getting it from the user straight from the form to the application. For some reason this doesn't seem to be bringing the newlines with it

Comment: Can you show us your code so that we can help you better? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sorry, probably would have helped.

https://github.com/wlox/wlox-frontend/blob/master/htdocs/settings.php

Info goes from here

To here:

https://github.com/wlox/wlox-api/blob/master/lib/User.php

Line 408

Comment: I forgot to add, the form is $personal